# Stochastic discount factor for factor research

Tags: factor-models, mean-variance, stochastic-discount

Often, after presenting a new factor technique, the paper calculates an SDF by doing $\Sigma ^{-1}\mu_F$ i.e. mean variance optimization on the factors. What is the significance of doing this ?

Comment: What is "the paper"?